# Problem when using a path in python terminal

Tags: python, terminal, path, pyinstaller, filepath

I am trying to use PyInstaller, but I'm running into some issues with using my path. My path is `C:\Users\2000036755\OneDrive - Fulton County Schools\Documents\Code\Python\PyGame\snake.py`. Every time I try to input the path into the terminal, I get this result.

```
~/C:\Users\2000036755\OneDrive : The term '~/C:\Users\2000036755\OneDrive' is not 
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.    
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ~/C:\Users\2000036755\OneDrive - Fulton County Schools\Documents\Code ...        
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (~/C:\Users\2000036755\OneDrive:Strin 
   g) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

It can't go through the path, and I can't rename it to something else. Is there a solution for this? The command I'm using is `cd C:\Users...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with a quote if there is spaces in the path

```
cd "C:\Users\2000036755\OneDrive - Fulton County Schools\Documents\Code\Python\PyGame\snake.py"
```